# Redirect to success page from paypal without waiting 10s

Tags: paypal, payment

I try a project demo about payment by Paypal. When the payment has success, I have to waiting 10s before redirect to my success page. So, I want to change 10s to 1s (or not waiting) to redirect. How can I do that ?

Thank all !

Answer (score 0):

You will need to switch to the [Express Checkout APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECGettingStarted/) in order to do that.  It will be a much smoother process overall.